# XML Parse \ and special character issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml-parsing

When I try to parse soap result. I got unwanted result.

I get this result

The final result :[{"UserID":9,"EMail":"1","UserName":"1","Password":"c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b","FullName":"1","Gender":"Kadın"}]

and parse it.

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes:%lu",(unsigned long)[responseData length]);

    NSString *theXml = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[responseData mutableBytes] length:[responseData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"The final result :%@",theXml);

    if (xmlParser) {
        xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: responseData];
        [xmlParser setDelegate:self];
        [xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:YES];
        [xmlParser parse];
    }
}

-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser didStartElement:(NSString *) elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *) namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *) qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"GetUserResult"]) {

        soapResults = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        elementFound = YES;
    }
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if (elementFound)
    {
        [soapResults appendString: string];
    }
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
 namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"GetUserResult"])
    {
        NSArray *userInfo = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:soapResults, nil];
        NSLog(@"%@", soapResults);
        NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);
    }
}
```

In first nslog is that what I want.

NSLOG 1: 
[{"UserID":9,"EMail":"1","UserName":"1","Password":"c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b","FullName":"1","Gender":"Kadın"}]

But when I put the soapresults into NSArray, I got this 
NSLOG 2:
[{\"UserID\":9,\"EMail\":\"1\",\"UserName\":\"1\",\"Password\":\"c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b\",\"FullName\":\"1\",\"Gender\":\"Kad\U0131n\"}]

How can I solve it? Thanks.

Comment: That's not XML. It looks a lot more like JSON.

Comment: Yes, result will be JSON. But I get this and try to parse it.

The final result :<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><GetUserResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><GetUserResult>[{"UserID":9,"EMail":"1","UserName":"1","Password":"c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b","FullName":"1","Gender":"Kadın"}]</GetUserResult></GetUserResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>

Comment: Looks like an Enterprise attempt at RESTful web services. You will need to parse JSON received as well.